# Python - SimpleGui - Listbox - After Search I lose the highlight

Tags: python, listbox, highlight, pysimplegui

I've a very simple interface where I have a listbox with my employee names and a Input text where I can put the name to search more quickly.

I've I don't put any text on the input I can select the employee name with a highlight like this:

[image]

But if I search for the name (and then I will update this element for the new list with only the names that contains the text that I write) I am not able to get the highlight, as you can see:

[image]

My code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg

employees_list = ['John','Pete','Anne','Jack','Golsing']
layout = [[sg.Input(visible=True,size=(15, 1), enable_events=True,key='-input-')]
        ,[sg.Listbox(values=employees_list,size=(15, 3),enable_events=True, select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_MULTIPLE, key='-employee-')]]

Window = sg.Window('DEV', layout)

while True:
    Event, Values = Window.read()

    if Event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    if Values['-input-'] != '':
        search = Values['-input-'].upper()
        new_employees = [x.upper() for x in employees_list if search in x]
        Window.Element('-employee-').Update(values=new_employees, select_mode=sg.LISTBOX_SELECT_MODE_MULTIPLE)
```

Has anyone been through this? How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle different event here,

```py
    if Values['-input-'] != '':
```

Here, you will do it if any event generated, so `Listbox` will be updated when you click `Listbox`, so selection will be set to none, that's why no item selected or highlighted.

So the code should be

```py
    if Event == '-input-' and Values['-input-'] != '':
```

And here you don't recover the listbox to full list when empty input. So maybe you need to handle another case for

```py
    if Event == '-input-' and Values['-input-'] == '':
        # update Listbox with values=employees_list
```